# Кнопка, рассчитать не выполняет своей функции

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qpushbutton

Пытаюсь сделать приложение на *PyQt*, которое считает конечную сумму, которую вкладчик получит по истечению периода вклада.

Кнопка, рассчитать, к сожалению, не выполняет своей функции.

Кто-нибудь может помочь с этим, пожалуйста?

```
import sys 
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

import deposits        # Это наш конвертированный файл дизайна

# Так как файл с дизайном будет полностью перезаписываться каждый раз при изменении дизайна, мы не будем 
# изменять его. Вместо этого мы создадим новый класс ExampleApp, который объединим с кодом дизайна для 
# использования всех его функций
summ, percent, period, capitalization = 1000.10, 5.5, 12, False

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, deposits.Ui_MainWindow):
    summ, percent, period, capitalization = 1000.10, 5.5, 12, False
    def __init__(self):
        # Это здесь нужно для доступа к переменным, методам
        # и т.д. в файле deposits.py
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  # Это нужно для инициализации нашего дизайна

    def deposit_summ(self):
        global summ
        summ = self.lineEdit.changed.connect(float(input()))

    def deposit_procent(self):
        global percent
        percent = self.lineEdit_2.changed.connect(float(input()))

    def deposit_period(self):
        global period
        period = self.lineEdit_3.changed.connect(int(input()))

    def deposit_capitalization(self):
        global capitalization
        if self.checkBox.isChecked == True:
            capitalization = True
    
    def push_button(self):
        self.pushButton.pressed.connect(self.get_result)

    def get_result(self):
        global summ
        if capitalization == False:
            result = summ + round(summ * (percent / 100), 2)
        elif capitalization == True:
            for _ in range(period):
                summ += round(summ * (percent / 100), 2) / period
        self.lineEdit_4.text(summ)
```

[image: Сама программа]

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему. В том числе и модуль `deposits.py`.

Comment: @S.Nick
Добрый день! Огромное спасибо за стремление помочь. Пока я не очень силен в python и в pyqt, в частности. Спросить лично у кого-либо у меня, к сожалению, нет возможности. deposits.py, deposits.ui, main.py и более адекватное main.py можно просмотреть здесь github.com/dogbusiness/vklady

Answer (score 0):

Я не проверял ваши формулы расчетов. Я прокомментировал код, который предложу вам изучить. Если что-то не понятно - спросите.

**main.py**

```
import sys 
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from deposits import Ui_MainWindow


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  
        
        # какие-то начальные установки, если они нужны ?
        self.lineEdit.setText(f'{1000.1012345:.2f}')
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(f'{5.5:.2f}')
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(f'{12}')
        
#                       vvvvvvv 
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get_result)
        
#   зачем вам кнопка ниже ??? для чего она ???
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.get_result)
        
        self.lineEdit_4.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit.setFocus()

    def get_result(self):
        if  not self.lineEdit.text() or \
            not self.lineEdit_2.text() or \
            not self.lineEdit_3.text():
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'Внимание', 
                'Заполните пожалуйста все поля для расчета.')
            self.lineEdit.setFocus()
            return
        
        # вытаскиваем исходные данные и преобразовываем их в нужный для расчета тип        
        summ = float(self.lineEdit.text())
        percent = float(self.lineEdit_2.text())
        period = int(self.lineEdit_3.text())

        #print(f'checkBox = {self.checkBox.isChecked()}') 
        if not self.checkBox.isChecked():
            summ = summ + round(summ * (percent / 100), 2)
        else:
            for _ in range(period):
                summ += round(summ * (percent / 100), 2) / period

        self.lineEdit_4.setText(f'{summ:.2f}')


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    window = ExampleApp()  
    window.show()  
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

**deposits.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(168, 360)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(168, 360))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 160, 121, 17))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 121, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 121, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 121, 21))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 121, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 110, 121, 16))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 130, 121, 21))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 190, 121, 21))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 240, 121, 16))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 260, 121, 21))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 300, 121, 21))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Капитализация?"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Сумма вклада</p></body></html>"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Процент вклада"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Срок вклада в месяцах"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Рассчитать"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Вы получите</p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Рассчитать снова"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]